# What is the given event $B$ called on $P(A \mid B)$?

Tags: probability, terminology, conditional-probability

Is there a widely used name for $B$ in conditional probability $P(A\mid B)$?

I found the name *condition event* on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), but it doesn't seem to be very common as long as searching on Google scholar.

Comment: I don't believe there is a standard name for it. I'd have said "conditioning event" myself, but I would have included the definition to avoid confusion.

Comment: You could just say "the condition".

Comment: You could just call it the *given*.